# Can binomial logistic regression be used with repeated measure predictors?

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, assumptions, predictor

I was reading about binomial logistic regression assumptions and a basic requirement seems to be : independence of observations. **So I was wondering if predictors could be repeated measures (pre-post treatment) in a binomial logistic regression?**

I have a dichotomous dependent variable (categories are mutually exclusive and exhaustive; yes or no) and I have several predictors (pre-post treatment). I want to know if results at T0 and/or T1 predicts the outcome yes or no (e.g. does T0 performance status and/or T1 performance status are good predictors outcome?).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is this like a difference in difference design?  If not, you could always use a generalized linear mixed effects model, which can handle repeated measurements.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand : "Is this like a difference in difference design?"

Comment: How would you handle this if the response variable were continuous instead of binomial?